# How to display same id of row in same id of 1st row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below output:

```
   Reg_id          class_id                  reg_date      
 2011213807261  0000111016294       2019-02-14 12:22:24.057
 2011213807254  0000111016294       2019-02-14 12:22:24.057
 2011214239559  0000111016447       2019-09-21 03:55:25.357
 2011214239573  0000111016447       2019-09-21 03:55:25.357
 4511999718167  0000111016455       2017-07-23 10:39:36.043
 4511999718235  0000111016455       2017-07-23 10:39:36.043
 4511999717931  0000111016456       2017-03-17 12:35:32.537
 4511999717924  0000111016456       2017-03-17 12:35:32.537
```

Above output I have same class id of two records.
I want 2nd row of same class id as 1st row put in same id of 1st row.

Needed output

```
 Reg_id            class_id          reg_date             Reg_id            class_id          reg_date 
2011213807261   0000111016294    2019-02-14 12:22:24.057  2011213807254  0000111016294   2019-02-14 12:22:24.057
2011214239559   0000111016447    2019-09-21 03:55:25.357  2011214239573  0000111016447   2019-09-21 03:55:25.357
4511999718167   0000111016455    2017-07-23 10:39:36.043  4511999718235  0000111016455   2017-07-23 10:39:36.043
4511999717931   0000111016456    2017-03-17 12:35:32.537  4511999717924  0000111016456   2017-03-17 12:35:32.537
```

I need output like above, same id records should display in front of same id of 1st record row.

Comment: What there is 2 column of `class_id` and having same value ?

Comment: Is there any order column able to represent 1st row or 2nd?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I was tried with `FOR XML PATH` but output is not getting proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ROW_NUMBER()` function as given below:

```sql
declare @TABLE Table(reg_id varchar(20), class_id varchar(20), regdate datetime)

insert into @table values
('2011213807261','0000111016294','2019-02-14T12:22:24.057')
,('2011213807254','0000111016294','2019-02-14T12:22:24.057');

WITH CTE_TableRank AS 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class_id ORDER BY reg_id) as rnk
    FROM @table
)
SELECT c1.reg_id, c1.class_id, c1.regdate, c2.reg_id, c2.class_id, c2.regdate
FROM CTE_TableRank AS c1 
INNER JOIN CTE_TableRank AS c2 ON c1.class_id = c1.class_id
WHERE c1.rnk = 1 AND c2.rnk = 2
```

| reg_id | class_id | regdate | reg_id | class_id | regdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011213807254 | 0000111016294 | 2019-02-14 12:22:24.057 | 2011213807261 | 0000111016294 | 2019-02-14 12:22:24.057 |

Comment: @DaleK, no problem. thanks for the edit. you are right. the query looks better now.